# Boost call method in other Boost Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

I have a stack with threads using Boost. I have 2 classes with method run, for example:

```
class class1 {
    public:
        class1::class1(){
            void run() { //I need to call getA
            }
        }
};

class class2 {
    private:
        float A;
    public:
        class2:class2() { A = 0; }
        void run() { A++; }
        float getA() { return A; }
};
```

In the main function, I have both run's methods as threads:

```
void main(){
    class1 c1;
    class2 c2;

    boost::thread t1(&class1::run,c1);
    boost::thread t1(&class2::run,c2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

I've unsucesfully tried using a mutex. I've also created a pointer of c2 into c1, but the value is not updated.

How could one class call a method in another class when their instances are in different threads?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with threading. `c1` can't modify `c2` because it knows nothing about `c2`. You'll have to pass it in a pointer to `c1` as a constructor parameter or `run` parameter for `c2` to call its functions.

Comment: I tried a pointer to c2 to call their functions, but when I call getA(), the return is 0 instead of the actual value that is running in the other thread.

Comment: I don't see any such attempt in your post

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, some clarifications:

- Classes are not objects in C++, they are mere compile-time constructs to group related stuff. So, "how could one class" should rather be "how could one instance" or "one class".
- Further, "when their instances are in different threads" doesn't make sense either, because threads (as opposed to processes) share the same memory space. However, you still need to reach the other object, for which you need a reference, which you somehow need to pass along.
- Lastly, to "Call [a] Method in other Boost Thread" is ambiguous. It could mean you want to invoke a method on a different object, which would be called by the same thread though. It could also mean that you want a different thread to call the method and then return the result to your thread, which is way more complicated. That would require some form of communication with that other thread.

Now, in order to get objects passed to a thread function, check out e.g. Boost.Bind. Since it doesn't matter that these things are called in a thread, you could also pass a reference to the `class2` instance to the ctor of `class1` and store it there. Much of that depends on what you actually want. However, one note still: If you share objects between threads, you will have to sync access to them somehow, e.g. using a mutex.

PS: C++11 has its own threads which I would prefer over Boost.Thread. They are mostly the same, but one of them is standard, while Boost still is an addon.